# XSS Cross Site Scripting - on JSP input tag

Tags: security, jsp, xss

The following piece of code in my JSP caused a cross site scripting vulnerability on the input tag.

```
<td id="locale-block" align="left" style="visibility: hidden; height: 0;">
    <input type="text" id="locale" name="locale" text="eng" value = "eng">eng
</td>
```

During Penetration testing they were able to alert some random message to the user by injecting a alert script in the value attribute of the tag as follows

```
</script><script>alert(1);</script><script>
```

What should be done to avoid this? Is there any simple solution which does not involve paid 3rd party paid library?

Answer (score 1):

There's actually a good 3rd party lib that takes care of sanitation pretty easily, called OWASP.

I first heard about it at JFokus 2014, from [WhiteHat Security Jim Manico](http://manico.net/), in his speech about JAVA Security.

Check it out: [here](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Java_HTML_Sanitizer_Project)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I do not want a JAVA security framework for now. I want jsp xss validation/prevention framework